# Laravel Session Duration

Tags: javascript, session, laravel

I have a Laravel Project (including authentication users). I need to log session duration time. That's easy if the user click on logout, but what about if the user closes the tab/window?

I thought to use JavaScript to manipulate that events or set a timeout to send an ajax request to the server to say "Hey! I'm online!" and then update session duration, but it seems is not efficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know for sure if a user is still loged in on your website. The closest way to check for this is indeed to use a javascript that makes an ajax call every x seconds. This is what Facebook used to do to check if users are still online.